# Обновление данных ячейки DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Здравствуйте. Есть ObservableCollection, которая биндится к DataGrid.
В таблице есть вычисляемое поле.
Т.е. Column3 = Column1 + Column2

Как обновлять DataGrid или коллекцию, или что? , чтобы после ввода Column1 и Column2 сразу изменялось значение Column3?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз вы уж написали тег MVVM: изменение значения должно быть в вашей VM. В VM-классе, ответственном за элемент `ObservableCollection`, подпишитесь на изменения значений `Column1` и `Column2`, и обновляйте `Column3` соответственно.

View всего лишь автоматически подхватывает изменения, делаемые в VM.

Comment: Естественно, изменения во VM. Но эти изменения не обновляются в UI, в частности, DataGrid.
Модель данных сгенерирована Entity Framework.

Comment: А причём здесь модель? У вас ObservableCollection не модельных элементов, надеюсь?

Comment: @VladD Нет, просто нужно было реализовать вычисляемое поле на уровне модели и тогда всё работает.)

Comment: @NekoSin4eG: а почему это помогло? Не должно было. Покажите свой VM-класс, реализующий строчку `DataGrid`.

Answer (score 1):

Реализовал в модели данных интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged и сделал нужное поле - вычисляемым.